# Azure VM Replication and Failover

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vhd

Here's the scenario:
I have an application that requires the existence of an Azure VM where all components of that application are contained in that one VM.  (I know.)  Naturally that VM exists in a datacenter like US-East or something like that.  Because it is self-contained, it cannot be load balanced. (I know.)

My question:
Is there a way this VM can be replicated to another datacenter similarly to Hyper-V replicas?  Or can I at least replicate the storage, and what would that process be?

Objective:
Having this resource existing in a single datacenter means it will be unavailable when that datacenter is unavailable.  I need to remove my reliance from that single datacenter.

I know this is not the ideal situation for any application, but it is the animal I need to work with for now until it can be redesigned.
Any advice you can provide is greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Site Recovery will do exactly what you want. One of the features is basically an hyper-v replica.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/site-recovery/